# Proving that an element is mapped to itself.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to prove something but it's not really working out.

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $ a < b$ Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be continuous. Proof that there exists a $c \in [a,b]$ so that $f(c)=c$

I get that $b$ is the maximum of the image of $f$ and $a$ is the minimum. I also get that because of $f$ its continuity we can apply the the intermediate value theorem, so there must exist $t \in [a,b]$ so that $f(t) = c$. But I cannot prove that one of these solutions must be $c$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: __Hint__: Consider $g(t) = f(t)-t$.

Comment: oh of course, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $f(a)=a$ or $f(b)=b$ we are finished. Thus we can suppose that $f(a)>a$ and $f(b)<b$. Then we have for the continuous function $g(t)=f(t)-t$ that
$g(a)=f(a)-a>0$ and $g(b)=f(b)-b<0$. So by intermediate Value Theorem there's a $c\in[a,b]$ with $g(c)=0$ and therefore
$$f(c)=g(c)+c=c,$$
what was to show.